# i am building a app using tkinter but theres an error showing "top" as an invaild syntax, how do i solve this

Tags: python, tkinter

i am learning python but i am on the early stages.....so i stupidly decided to build a app...i know its stupid but i still do try, i make the program but theres an unvalid indent at " from Tkinter import" specificly at "from" ....how can i solve this..here's the code:

```
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
def proces():

I=Entry.get(E1)
R=Entry.get(E2)
v=Entry.get(E3)
I=int(I)
R=int(R)
v=int(v)
n = 0.5
V = v * R * I * n
Entry.insert(E4,0,V)
print(V)

top = tkinter
top.title("potential difference calculator")
L1 = Label(top, text="Potential Diffrence Calculator",).grid(row=0,column=1)
L2 = Label(top, text="current",).grid(row=1,column=0)
L3 = Label(top, text="Resistace",).grid(row=2,column=0)
L4 = Label(top, text="volume",).grid(row=3,column=0)
L4 = Label(top, text="Answer",).grid(row=4,column=0)
E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E1.grid(row=1,column=1)
E2 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E2.grid(row=2,column=1)
E3 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E3.grid(row=3,column=1)
E4 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E4.grid(row=4,column=1)
B=Button(top, text ="Submit",command = proces).grid(row=5,column=1,)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Isn’t a `try:` line missing above the included code?

Comment: i just figured and your right and i edited that but after that there were 100 problems so i am just going to leave the idea of an app for future

Comment: ```def process``` expects the code below to be indented. 
also looks like you have used the code without understanding the intended purpose of the lines.(as you may see many variables would come as not defined in your error list)

Comment: i did actually indent the code in the program but while copy and pasting the code in the snippet box during writing the question but for some reason it showed it as a text so i had to make it like a code but forgot the indent in the code

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine

```
top = Tk()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25979098)